# Coloring the options in a selectInput in R Shiny

Tags: r, colors, shiny

I have a shiny app with a `selectInput` in the UI.

Suppose I have in my UI:

```
selectInput("my_select_input", "Select Letter", c("A", B", "C", "D"))
```

And I want to specify that the boxes for the `A` and C choices should be filled blue and the boxes for the `B` and `D` should be filled red.

Comment: It's easier to help if you provide some minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that has running code to create the selectInput.

Comment: Consider doing this in javascript instead - you can pass custom javascript to your app.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could help me understand how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using CSS. For more on how to style a Shiny application with CSS see [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).

I have included a demo application which includes CSS as a string. In practice I would store CSS styles in a separate file, see the article linked above. If you are not familiar with CSS I will briefly summarize the selectors used, more on CSS selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Summary of CSS selectors,

- `#my_select_input` looks for a tag with id `my_select_input`
- `~ .selectize-control` says we actually want a sibling tag of `#my_select_input` and that sibling must have the class `selectize-control`
- `.option` says we want child tag(s) of the above tag(s) and those child tag(s) must have the class `option`
- finally, the `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` let us control which of the child tags are style will apply to, where `odd` selects the first, third, and fifth (etc.) child and `even` selects the second, fourth, and sixth (etc.) child.

With all that said, here is the demo application.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style("
        #my_select_input ~ .selectize-control .option:nth-child(odd) {
          background-color: rgba(30,144,255,0.5);

        }

        #my_select_input ~ .selectize-control .option:nth-child(even) {
          background-color: rgba(205,92,92,0.5);
        }
        "
      )
    ),
    selectInput(
      inputId = "my_select_input",
      label = "Select Letter", 
      choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

  }
)
```

If you wanted to apply the red/blue coloration to all selectize inputs in your application you could drop the `#my_select_input ~` prefix. If you wanted to apply a variant of this style to a different selectize input you could change `my_select_input` and tweak the background color.
[image: colored selectinput]